# Getting nothing from sqlite3 INNER JOIN

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two tables in a sqlite3 database, movies and castxxxx and I am trying to inner join on the movie ids.  Here are the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (id integer, name text, score integer);
CREATE TABLE castxxxx (movie_id integer, cast_id integer, cast_name text,
FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id));
```

Here are examples of castxxxx:

```
770876554,770773491,"Edmund Pegge"||
770876554,770925843,"Noel Travarthen"||
770972512,335716545,"Noam Chomsky"||
```

and here is a record from movies whose id matches the movie_id 770876554 on castxxxx:

```
770876554|Anzacs - The War Down Under|48
```

When I run inners joins, nothing is returned. e.g.

```
SELECT castxxxx.cast_name
FROM movies
INNER JOIN castxxxx ON castxxxx.movie_id = movies.id;
```

As an additional question, I am importing data from a csv, but I am not allowed to when a field is set as the primary key.  How do I set a primary key after the import if there is no access to the ALTER TABLE command in sqlite?

I have tried many different combinations.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The import went wrong (everything was written into the first column). Show what exactly you did.

Comment: Aha. I did ...    .import filename castxxxx

Edit:  Once I typed that, it occurred to me what I have been doing wrong.  I needed to put it into '.mode csv'.  The hours I have spent looking at the wrong thing.  Thank you very much!!! Big AHA moment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as pointed out by CL was that I forgot to change to ...

```
.mode csv
```

before running my...

```
.import filename castxxxx
```

Thank you CL!